# rails refinerycms s3 upload error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms, fog

I'm trying to configure RefineryCMS to use Fog for S3 uploads.  Here's the error I'm getting:

```
ArgumentError in Refinery::Admin::ImagesController#create
The following keys are invalid: :url
```

My configuration in config/initializers/refinery/core.rb:

```
config.s3_bucket_name = '(mybucket)'
config.s3_access_key_id = '(mykey)'
config.s3_secret_access_key = '(mysecret)'
config.s3_backend = true
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue, although in a different setup (dragonfly with S3 datastore). Seems like `fog` is the issue.

Try to use an older version of `fog`. I updated my `Gemfile` to use an older version of `fog`.

`gem 'fog', '1.4.0'`

and then run

`bundle install`

I tried every single version from 1.9.0 to 1.4.0, and 1.4.0 was the first version where my uploads were working again. I will update my post if I find a way to get this working with 1.9.0

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick fix. Stick in an initializer.

```
module Excon
 class Connection
   VALID_CONNECTION_KEYS << :url
 end 
end
```